# What is a gib/gib kill?

Tags: team-fortress-2

In TF2, I have heard of a term known as "Gib" What exactly does this term mean? There is even a strange part called: "gib kills" What does that mean? Low health kill? Adrenaline kill?

Could I please have some clarification on what both terms mean? Both the term "gib" itself and "gib kills".

Comment: Gib - as in giblets are all that's left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you kill someone with explosives and their body parts fly around - that's a gib kill. You can also gib kill yourself.

"gib" more or less means a fragment or a body part of a killed/destroyed character.